# Use individual ratchet icon as inline css

Tags: css, svg

I am using just one icon from the ratchet collection (http://goratchet.com/components/). I was wondering if I can embed the SVG definition of the icon directly into my '.css' file.

I.e. something like..

```
.tick {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml ... *svg-definition-in-here* ...
}
```

The code for the icon of interest from ratchicons.svg is ...

```
<glyph glyph-name="check" unicode="&#xe810;" d="m857 537l-81 83l-354-372l-135 128l-81-83l216-211l435 455z" horiz-adv-x="1000" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you embed the glyph data in a path and transform it so it's the other way up you get this.

```css
html, body, svg {
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -900 900 900">
  <path transform="scale(1, -1)" d="m857 537l-81 83l-354-372l-135 128l-81-83l216-211l435 455z"/>
</svg>
```

Then all you need to do is embed it...

```css
.tick {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -900 900 900"><path transform="scale(1, -1)" d="m857 537l-81 83l-354-372l-135 128l-81-83l216-211l435 455z"/></svg>')
}
```

```html
<div class="tick"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Robert Longson's answer would be to use the `<foreignObject>` method which is supported in most modern browsers apart from IE.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ratchet/2.0.2/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<svg width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <foreignObject width="100" height="50">

    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <span class="icon icon-check"></span>
    </body>

  </foreignObject>

</svg>
```

- [`<foreignObject>` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)